# How to get image in a Particles.js script in php?

Tags: javascript, php, particles.js

I was trying to convert my static html to wordpress theme. When I converted it I ran into a problem. I was using Particle JS and in particlejs script I was using image mode but when I converted my project to php images didn't show up. I think its about php directory system ( I'dont know much about php )
I tried to fix this problem like img problem. How can I solve this problem ?

I added `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().` this line in srcs of the images but when I try this method in js it doesn't work.

[particleJS script I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDyFc.png
[how I solved image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww5R2.png))

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't include images of your code instead copy and paste it in the question.